# joomla Top menu not show in Internet explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, joomla

i had developed joomla site,[Yogamother.com](http://yogamother.com/).
In this site top menu have drop down menu.
this menu show all other browsers. but it not show in internet explorer 6.
And also some articles that don't appear in internet explorer.(yoga dictionary,what is yoga)
please advise me. how can i require it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***IE Troubleshoot***

There Should be **MARKUP ERROR** in your Joomla template.So please check your markup tags are opened and closed correctly.

You can validate your markup in **W3c Validator**
http://validator.w3.org/

You also can Troubleshoot some other script problem ... Some are the common mistakes listed here,
http://lifescaler.com/2008/05/ie-object-required-error-and-other-common-coding-mistakes/

Answer (score 2):

I don't have IE6 on anything so I am using DebugBar's IETester so I can't guarantee that I am seeing the same thing as real IE6. That said, it looks like a z-index problem to me. In IETester you can select the area the menu is supposed to be in and it will copy all of the next from the menu. It would appear that the menu is under the background image for some reason.

You should seriously consider getting rid of the tables as well. Your design is not particularly complicated and would be easy to write tableless. It will speed up the rendering and clean up your code considerably.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it has something to do with IE6 position problems when using "width:100%" ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest adding this to your CSS:

```
* html #sfmenu { zoom: 1; }
```

The [Star HTML hack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_filter#Star_HTML_hack) will ensure that only IE6 gets this style. The `zoom: 1` gives the menu "[layout](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html)", a mysterious property that fixes lots of things in IE6. (I've tested this by adding it to your site using the [IE Web Developer Toolbar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_Developer_Toolbar).)

After doing this, you'll see the menu is shifted up by about 30px. There is a `<hr>` in your menu HTML (in the "Video" section) that is causing extra space below the menu. I suggest removing this `<hr>`, or at least hiding it with `display: none` for IE6.