# Joomla vs IE browser compatability

Tags: internet-explorer, joomla, visibility

Website was built by another developer. I'm hired to help complete updates. Everything looks great in Chrome, Safari, Firefox, but not Internet Explorer. The menu is unreadable on one page (missing background carousel) and on other pages, the menu shows as a bullet list which expands all other data either behind it or below it depending what device you view the page on. Also, sections of information (carousel, images) are not showing...

I already know IE is problematic to developers, however what would cause all of these issues? Where would I even begin to investigate or what coding fix is well known out there to make this site work JUST ON IE? Ridiculous! Especially since it works beautifully across all other platforms. Anyone else run into this? What did you do to rectify the situation?

Answer (score 1):

I think I may just have found a possible solution...based off another question I searched for:

[joomla Top menu not show in Internet explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482750/joomla-top-menu-not-show-in-internet-explorer)

There was a site that appears to be helpful 
"You can validate your markup in W3c Validator
http://validator.w3.org/ "

Thank you @Gowri for you advice on another question! I'll definitely try this out and hope it helps. :-)

Answer (score 0):

in my own humble experience Joomla is not the problem, but mostly the used libraries are (newer versions of jquery, newer version of bootstrap for example) and more modern coding css/script - wise. IE lacks support on a lot of things that are really common to use nowadays.

the problems you discribe look to script-issues to me, but you'll have to be more specific to get any specific answers. The only thing i can give you is not to pinpoint your ploblem on joomla, but more on the used template.